# Different Types of Readonly Properties

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In C# 6 you can have the following property:

```
public Uri MyProperty => new Uri();
```

Or you can have this:

```
public Uri MyProperty1 { get; } = new Uri();
```

Whats the difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first returns a new `Uri` object each time you access the property - the second *initializes* the property to a new `Uri` object and gives the same object every time.

Comment: Do you know what that's called?  I'm assuming it's new to 6.0?

Comment: The first is an expression bodied property - the second is a getter-only automatic property.  Both are new to C# 6.0.

Comment: Golly, why would anyone want that first one?  I think I would prefer a method

Comment: @MickyD Sure, a method would do the exact same thing.  It's purely a style choice. It's more "functional".

Comment: I guess so :)  +1

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that this will create a new instance of `Uri` every time:

```
public Uri MyProperty => new Uri();
```

And this will work with backing field with assigned value:

```
public Uri MyProperty1 { get; } = new Uri();
```